# Spring Boot 3: skip internal redirect behavior

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redirect, spring-security

After upgrading to Spring Boot 3 I faced a strange behaviour. I have an endpoint that is called by the outside service and which returns `302` status code. Take a look at the code snippet below.

```java
@GetMapping("/callback")
@Hidden
@SneakyThrows
public void callback(@NotNull @RequestParam(name = "code") String authorizationCode,
        @NotNull @RequestParam(name = "state") String state,
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {

    try {
        ...
        httpResponse.addCookie(jwtTokenCookie););
        httpResponse.sendRedirect(state.targetUri());
    } catch (IntegrationException e) {
        throw new ControllerException(BAD_REQUEST, e);
    }
}
```

The thing is that I don't receive the `302` status code anymore. Instead, Spring does the actual redirect inside and returns the result of `targetUri()` endpoint invocation. But I don't want that. I need to receive the `302` status code with the actual redirect value.

I tried to refactor code a bit:

```java
final var jwtTokenCookie = cookieService.createJwtCookie(userContext);httpResponse.addCookie(jwtTokenCookie);
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders.setLocation(new URI(ssoState.targetUri()));
return new ResponseEntity<>(httpHeaders, FOUND);
```

But it didn't work. Seems like Spring Security has registered some filter that checks all `3xx` responses. Can I turn it off somehow?

### EDIT 1

I also tried to tune the `TestRestTemplate` instance to manually disable possible redirects. Look at the code snippet below.

```java
testRestTemplate = new TestRestTemplate(
            restTemplateBuilder, null, null, TestRestTemplate.HttpClientOption.ENABLE_COOKIES
        );
```

As you can see, I don't pass the `HttpClientOption.ENABLE_REDIRECTS` option. Therefore, the `TestRestTemplate` should return the result as-is. Anyway, I still get the redirected URL response value.

So, I bet that the service does redirects but not the client.

Here are the **response** headers:

```
Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate",
Connection:"keep-alive",
Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8",
Date:"Tue, 29 Nov 2022 19:25:54 GMT",
Expires:"0",
Keep-Alive:"timeout=60",
Pragma:"no-cache",
Transfer-Encoding:"chunked",
Vary:"Origin",
"Access-Control-Request-Method",
"Access-Control-Request-Headers",
X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff",
X-Frame-Options:"DENY",
X-XSS-Protection:"0"
```

The request headers are empty.

### EDIT 2

I've also tried to upgrade the springdoc library to the `2.x.x`.

The previous version is

```
implementation "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.13"
```

The new version is

```
implementation "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.0.2"
```

That didn't help anyhow. I also turned on the TRACE logging for more information. Take a look at the code below to see what I got.

```
21:10:42.223 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Using @ExceptionHandler ...SsoController#handleRedirectException(RedirectException)
21:10:42.223 TRACE o.s.w.m.HandlerMethod - Arguments: [...RedirectException: Redirect to /api/accounts]
21:10:42.224 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor - Using 'text/plain', given [text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*] and supported [*/*]
21:10:42.224 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved [...RedirectException: Redirect to /api/accounts]
21:10:42.224 TRACE o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet - No view rendering, null ModelAndView returned.
21:10:42.225 DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet - Completed 302 FOUND, headers={masked}
21:10:42.225 TRACE o.s.s.w.h.w.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
21:10:42.228 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@45d1efc3, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@193e95a8, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@2b359a0f, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@5df041, org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter@7b0eeb99, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@31324b57, ...JwtAuthenticationFilter@504b132d, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@387ee53c, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@5cf6aa48, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@1a2e5110, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@419ae2fd, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@3fed07ba, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@6ce03f94]] (1/1)
21:10:42.228 DEBUG o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy - Securing GET /api/accounts
21:10:42.228 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy - Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/13)
21:10:42.229 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy - Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/13)
21:10:42.229 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy - Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/13)
21:10:42.229 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy - Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/13)
21:10:42.229 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy - Invoking CharacterEncodingFilter (5/13)
21:10:42.229 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy - Invoking LogoutFilter (6/13)
...
```

As you can see, there is some filter that catches the `302` and trying to proceed the redirect to `/api/accounts` internally instead of simply returning the status code to the client.

According to logs, the `FilterChainProxy` starts the unwanted redirect behavior. However, it's not a conrcrete bean but a container that is used widely across Spring components. Any ideas how to disable the internal redirect?

Comment: Shpw your requests and responses with headers. The server doesn't resolve redirects, you client does it.

Comment: @dur I updated the answer. Shortly, the client probably does no redirects

Answer (score 0):

You need to throw your exception in the route processing and handle it your own Handler by issuing the code http_code=302 and http_text=redirect_bla_bla_bla at first. Second you need OnlyIn exchange pattern on your redirect.

Comment: That didn't hellp. I tried to throw custom exception and return ResponseEntity with 302 status inside the `@ExceptionHandler`. But still the service does redirect internally